# Excel Vlookup between two tables

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a table that has two columns (name, item number) and then I have a second table of the list of the same names and a blank column called 'Material needed?'

All im trying to do is have VLOOKUP the drawing name and if it has a value in the Item number column then the material needed column return yes, and if that drawing number doesnt have a value in item number it returns no. Below is a picture showing what I have and what I am trying to do in the Mat Needed column.

[image]

Comment: Multiple ways to do this... you could use IF and SUMIFS for example.

Comment: `=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"no","yes")`